# C# How do I read from a list in a .txt file and put them into a list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I display them in a list box, I just get "(Collection)" written instead of the actual text.

Comment: Can you also share the code you are using?

Comment: without some code it'll be hard to help

Answer (score 2):

You should read line by line of your text file and add them to a list. After it you can set your `ListBox` `DataSource` by your list. Try :

```
   const string f = "TextFile1.txt";

    // 1
    // Declare new List.
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    // 2
    // Use using StreamReader for disposing.
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
    {
        // 3
        // Use while != null pattern for loop
        string line;
        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
        // 4
        // Insert logic here.
        // ...
        // "line" is a line in the file. Add it to our List.
        lines.Add(line);
        }
    }

    // 5
    // Print out all the lines.
    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

[Read More](http://www.dotnetperls.com/readline)

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ for doing that:

```
var list = new List<string>();
var data = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").ToList();
foreach (var item in data)
{
    list.Add(item);
}
```

**Update**:
Actually it doesn't need to iterate the `data` and adding it to new list, this line gives you a list that contains each line of the file:

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").ToList();
```